# What does Edit>Preferences>Appearance>Multiplication>Use symbol

Tags: front-end, display, customization

I am using Mathematica Version 12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021).

I would like to see multiplication asterisk for all products on output. I know that this can be requested per expression by appending `\\ InputForm`.

Somewhere I read about **Edit>Preferences>Appearance>Multiplication>Use symbol** and it was claimed that this has the same effect without having to append or all products on output. I know that this can be requested per expression by appending `\\ InputForm`.

However, when I execute the expression

`a b` or `à*b`

both return `a b` although * is selected as multiplication symbol in **Edit>Preferences>Appearance>Multiplication>Use symbol**:

[image: preferences for multiplication symbol]

**Did I get it wrong?**
**Or is it a quirk in the current version?**

Comment: Notice that there's not a checkbox for "Symbols" as there are for functions, linebreaks, and numbers.  This way of displaying products is fairly new, and they don't seem to have included a way to insert multiplication symbols between symbols or all factors. I'd think there would be an `All`  option. One might be able to overwrite `MakeBoxes` for `Times`, I suppose, if it's important.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was wrong! They did implement `"Symbols"`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 AutoMultiplicationSymbol -> {"LineBreaks", "Functions", "Numbers", 
   "Symbols"}]
```

It's just not in the preferences.  This is documented in [`AutoMultiplicationSymbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoMultiplicationSymbol.html) .

Comment: Ha! You cannot start an answer with "Ha!" apparently.  Twice it was removed automatically. But you can start a comment with it :)

Comment: Thank you., Michael E2, Thank you also for the link to the explanation in the help system. Can you explain to me why the multiplication sign is written with such a faint shade of gray that you can hardly make it out? Quite different from a plus sign! That comes with the same degree of blackness as normal writing. Any idea how to let the asterisk appear like normal writing?

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen I can't really explain, but I can guess: In input cells, the `*` is gray when not actually present in the input, and it is black when typed. Plus must always be typed by the user. As for output cells, I suppose they took the same approach. Traditionally the multiplication signs are not part of the output, and that is still true: Use the menu command Cell > Show Expression to see that the multiplication signs are missing, but the plus signs are present. The gray `*` or cross is added by the FE to the displayed expressions.

Comment: A side effect (bug) in the Documentation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ee6H.png (version 12.3.1 on Windows).

Comment: @Alexey's bug also shows up in the INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR (and elsewhere): https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWj8n.png